# Check key's array with value's array and set it as value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a question for you.
My PHP code is composed by these below arrays and my intention is to merge them into one, as you can see at the bottom of the topic.
These arrays are divided into 2 different variables: $array1 and $array2.

```
Array ($array1)
(
    [0] => 2016-11-11
    [1] => 2016-11-10
    [2] => 2016-11-09
    [3] => 2016-11-08
    [4] => 2016-11-07
    [5] => 2016-11-06
    [6] => 2016-11-05
)
1
Array ($array2)
(
    [2016-11-11] => 0
    [2016-11-10] => 0
    [2016-11-08] => 0
    [2016-11-07] => 0
    [2016-11-06] => 0
)
1
```

And this is what I expect this program will do:

```
Array
(
    [2016-11-11] => 0,
    [2016-11-10] => 0,
    [2016-11-09] => NULL,
    [2016-11-08] => 0,
    [2016-11-07] => 0,
    [2016-11-06] => 0,
    [2016-11-05] => NULL
)
1
```

How can I set my code so that it returns me the previous array? How can I solve this problem? Can anyone help me?

I tried:

```
$array1 = array( 
    "2016-11-11", 
    "2016-11-10", 
    "2016-11-09", 
    "2016-11-08",
    "2016-11-07",
    "2016-11-06",
    "2016-11-05"
);
$array2 = array();
while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc())
{
    $array2[$row1["datesend"]] = $row1["error"];
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Or you expect us to write code for you?

Comment: Your edit is not what you tried but how you build your arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will work for you:

```
$array1 = array('2016-11-11','2016-11-10','2016-11-09','2016-11-08','2016-11-07','2016-11-06','2016-11-05');
$array2 = array('2016-11-11' => 0,'2016-11-10' => 0,'2016-11-08' => 0,'2016-11-07' => 0,'2016-11-06' => 0);

$result = array();
foreach($array1 as $a){
    if(isset($array2[$a]))
        $result[$a] = $array2[$a];
    else
        $result[$a] = NULL;
}
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
echo '</pre>'
```

Outpur is:

```
array(7) {
  ["2016-11-11"]=>
  int(0)
  ["2016-11-10"]=>
  int(0)
  ["2016-11-09"]=>
  NULL
  ["2016-11-08"]=>
  int(0)
  ["2016-11-07"]=>
  int(0)
  ["2016-11-06"]=>
  int(0)
  ["2016-11-05"]=>
  NULL
}
```

*I hope it helps*

Comment: Many thanks. Works! There is only a problem.... How can I choose if the value is NULL? I tried with this code but without success:
`foreach($result as $key => $value){`
 `if( $value > 0)`
        `{`
  `echo "<td class=\"danger\">In errore</td>";`
 `}elseif($value == 0)`
 `{`
  `echo "<td class=\"success\">Tutto OK</td>";`
 `}`
 `elseif($value == "N/D")`
 `{`
  `echo "<td></td>";`
 `}`
`}`

Comment: use : `elseif($value === NULL)` to match against `NULL` value. No problem. Happy Coding!